# Is Swift Package Manager practical locally?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

During the development of our app we're often creating blank Xcode projects on the side to experiment with potential features, fundamental changes, or just playing around. Whenever we do this we're manually copying quite a few classes to "get started". It could be anything from convenient extensions to actual API-implementation.
As far as I can tell, Swift Package Manager could make this a lot easier for us.

I've been reading up on the subject, but I can't help but feeling that it could be very "overkill". It sounds okay, but when looking at how this can be implemented I have a few thoughts;

• Do all the files of a package target have to be in the same folder? It seems messy.

• To be able to use this package in an "experiment app", would I have to keep all the package-code in its own (not necessarily hosted) git? If the alternative is to copy the package itself, what makes this different than just copying the classes?

• Would I have to "import MyExtensionPackage" everywhere where I would use any of these?

I'm having a hard time finding the border between this being practical and this being extra work/overkill for our needs.

If possible, I'd like to have everything in the same project, and only have to deal with one git - as we have today - but still have the ability to "group" our functionality into packages with internal dependencies, without losing the file structure. - and then have the ability to do some swift package manager magic to use our packages in other projects.

Can I somehow group existing functions in our project (like API or convenient extensions) into packages without having to stress with different GIT-repositories or submodules, and still be able to use the packages outside that project?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may just be looking for importing a framework into a playground and keeping that in your project so you have a convenient scratchpad. There are a lot of articles online about how to do this.

> Do all the files of a package target have to be in the same folder? It seems messy.

They do not. You can specify which directory contains your source code and then exclude specific internal directories that you do not want to expose.

> To be able to use this package in an "experiment app", would I have to keep all the package-code in its own (not necessarily hosted) git?

The code you want to consume with SPM does need to be under version control.

> If the alternative is to copy the package itself, what makes this different than just copying the classes?

I don't think that's the alternative. You could also keep a sample project with your code and depend on the build output of your libraries... maybe misunderstanding this one.

> Would I have to "import MyExtensionPackage" everywhere where I would use any of these?

Yes.